# function for multiple conditions in pandas using dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a function that uses a dataframe and a dictionary and returns a dataframe based on the conditions in the dictionary. My code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
column_names=['name','surname','age']
lfa=[("tom","jones",44),("elvis","prestley",50),("jim","reeves",30)]
lfa=pd.DataFrame(lfa,columns=column_names)

def flip(df,conditions):
   return (df[(df['name'].isin(['tom']))& (df['surname'].isin(['jones']))])

filter={'name':'tom','age':44}
flip(lfa,filter)
```

I am struggling to find the most efficient way of returning data based on conditions in the dictionary. ie if I pass a filter of name=tom and age=44, it should apply those conditions in the function.

NOTE: I am trying to build a generic function that can take in any dataframe with a flexible set of conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = lfa[lfa[list(f.keys())].eq(f).all(axis=1)]

print (df)
  name surname  age
0  tom   jones   44
```

**Details**:

First filter columns by keys of dictionary:

```
print (lfa[list(f.keys())])
    name  age
0    tom   44
1  elvis   50
2    jim   30
```

Compare by dictionary:

```
print (lfa[list(f.keys())].eq(f))
    name    age
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

And then test if all values match per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (lfa[list(f.keys())].eq(f).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

If possible some keys no match:

```
f={'name':'tom','age':44, 'aa':78}

df = lfa[lfa.reindex(f.keys(), axis=1).eq(f).all(axis=1)]

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, surname, age]
Index: []
```

Comment: is there a way to apply a condition similar to : f={'name':['tom','elvis']}

Comment: @NumberLogic - Is possible create all lists like `f={'name':['tom','elvis'], 'age':[44]}` - it means also change `44` to one element list `[4]` ?

Comment: I mean if I want to get the first and second records, I was thinking of something like , f={'name':['tom','elvis'], 'age':[44,50]} ie pick any records that have names of tom or elvis and age of 44 or 50

Comment: @NumberLogic - OK, if all values are lists then use `df = lfa[lfa[list(f.keys())].isin(f).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: any idea how to update the line above if some keys dont match ?

Comment: @NumberLogic - I think the best is post new question.